# Fulltext query results incorrectly ordered by scores

Tags: c#, full-text-search, ravendb, lucene.net

I have a RavenDB database with a few documents that look like this:

```
public class TextDocument
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string IndexedText { get; set; }
}
```

I have also defined a fulltext index, defined as follows:

```
public class TextIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<TextDocument>
{
    public TextIndex()
    {
        Map = docs =>
              from doc in docs
              select new { doc.IndexedText };

        Analyze(x => x.IndexedText, 
            "Lucene.Net.Analysis.StopAnalyzer, Lucene.Net");

        Indexes.Add(x => x.IndexedText, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
}
```

Let's assume that I have three documents, for which the `IndexedText` consists of 500-1000 words of *Lorem Ipsum* text.

Next, I have a list of search terms that I want to query:

```
private string[] _searchCriteria = new[]
        {
            "venenatis OR tortor OR tellus",
            "justo OR facilisis OR iaculis",
            "dignissim OR sodales OR aenean",
            "in OR ornare OR bibendum OR orci",
            "magna OR id OR hendrerit OR dapibus",
            "metus OR nunc OR eleifend OR praesent",
            "accumsan OR in OR turpis OR venenatis",
            "at OR bibendum OR in",
            "primis OR sit OR interdum",
            "eu OR enim OR massa"
        };
```

I perform one search for each search term and display the Lucene Scores of the search results, in order:

```
public void Search()
{
    using (var ds = CreateMyDocumentStore())
    using (var session = ds.OpenSession())
    {
        foreach (var criterion in _searchCriteria)
        {
            var results = session.Query<TextDocument, TextIndex>()
                                    .Search(x => x.IndexedText, criterion)
                                    .OrderByScore()
                                    .ToList();

            Console.WriteLine("--- Result scores for [{0}]:", criterion);

            foreach (var textDocument in results)
            {
                var score = session.Advanced.GetMetadataFor(textDocument)
                                    .Value<double>("Temp-Index-Score");
                Console.WriteLine(score);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In most cases the output appears normal (highest scores first), but once in a while I get anomalies like these:

```
...
--- Result scores for [magna OR id OR hendrerit OR dapibus]:
1.98572421
2.80171227
2.32371736
--- Result scores for [metus OR nunc OR eleifend OR praesent]:
2.80171227
1.98572421
2.32371736
...
```

What's weird is that although I asked for the results ordered by Lucene score (descending), the output above is clearly not sorted.

I also noticed that the longer the search terms, the more frequently I get these kinds of anomalies.

- Shouldn't the results always be ordered descending by score?
- Is there something I'm doing wrong in the above code?

I am using build *2.5.2700*.

The full code to reproduce the issue is available at: http://pastebin.com/K3bJ9Fsg (too long to post in this question)

---

Update: at [Vladimir Frolov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1786606/vladimir-frolov)'s advice, I tried opening a different session for each query and this solved the problem.

I'd like to know, however: is it *that* bad to reuse a session instance for multiple queries? Is it expected to get anomalous results in such a scenario?

Comment: May be something like `.Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResults())` (http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/appendixes/lucene-score)?

Comment: @VladimirFrolov I also tried that, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Or try open new session for each criterion.

Comment: @VladimirFrolov Thanks! Your suggestion solved my problem. I'm still curious if reusing the session is *that* bad and I'm awaiting an answer that would clarify that. If I don't get such an answer, I'll gladly accept yours.

Comment: Maybe it's the session that caches the documents and though never updates the meta data (and thus `Temp-Index-Score`)

Comment: @ThomasFreudenberg yes, it could be that. I'm not sure whether this is a bug in RavenDb or it's just expected not to work (and require separate sessions per query).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like race condition between evaluation of Lucene scores, which takes place in background thread, and displaying them to the user (`.Value<double>("Temp-Index-Score")`). Probably, sometimes the scores from previous criteria are shown. The solution is to has own session for each search criterion.

Comment: Yes, that must be the cause. Thanks!